# how to printf onmouseover="document.thumb.src=' ' "

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

please help me,I can't get

```
<a href="http://localhost/newwoo/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/shoes_isec1365498.jpg" class="zoom" onmouseover="document.thumb.src= **'http://localhost/newwoo/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/shoes_isec1365498.jpg'**" ></a>
```

run this:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="%s" onmouseover="document.thumb.src= '.$image_link.'" ></a>', $image_link, $image_class, $image_title ), $attachment_id, $post->ID, $image_class );
```

only get

```
<a href="http://localhost/newwoo/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/shoes_isec1365498.jpg" class="zoom" onmouseover="document.thumb.src= *http://localhost/newwoo/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/shoes_isec1365498.jpg*" ></a>
```

how to add ' ' to onmouseover,please tell me ,thank you!

Comment: thanks, I got it 
onmouseover="document.thumb.src=\'%s\'"

your idea are right, I am a beginner for php, sorry let you see ugly code. 
:)
I will try to add js to control html.my english is not good. thank you again. I really don't know I get answer so quickly here, this wonderful place, it is my first time to ask question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `''` by escaping them using backslashes.

The following example will output `''`:

```
echo '\'\'';
```

Answer (score 0):

avoid using the html attributes to include javascript code, instead try to refactor your code to put this functionality in a js file, cacheable and cleaner!